# Self referencing list mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a self referencing list for category and children. Each category has a list of children which are as well categories, but the auto-mapper is only applied for the first level of the model.

```cs
CreateMap<Category, CategoryForReturnDto> ()
    .ForMember (dest => dest.ItemsCount, opt => {
        int number = 0;
        opt.ResolveUsing (src => {
            return RecursiveItemsCount (src, number);
        });
    })
    .ForMember (dest => dest.Children, opt => { });
```

```cs
public class Category 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryForReturnDto
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ItemsCount { get; set; }
     public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
     public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Didn't you want to make `CategoryForReturnDto.Children` a `ICollection<CategoryForReturnDto>`? It would make more sense.

Comment: the childrens have the same structure as the item itself and they will also have childrens ...

Comment: @HassanKalach What is your goal with your second `ForMember()` setting for the `Children` property? And why do you expect that the full tree is converted? The `Children` property don't need to be converted since the types matches.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes your correct i did not think about it correctly

Comment: @Progman i got no clue i am trying to figure out how to make automapper work with sub children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fix was to have inside automapper profile

```
        CreateMap<Category, CategoryForReturnDto> ()
            .ForMember (dest => dest.ItemsCount, opt => {
                int number = 0;
                opt.ResolveUsing (src => {
                    return RecursiveItemsCount (src, number);
                });
            });
```

and inside the dto

```
public class CategoryForReturnDto
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int ItemsCount { get; set; }
     public ICollection<CategoryForReturnDto> Children { get; set; }
     public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```